# Sonatype nexus downloaded jars location

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, nexus

I have deployed Sonatype nexus war file to my Tomcat 7. Then add all need info to the pom.xml and all work good. I can download jars from my own nexus repo. Now nexus works as proxy - its download external dependence etc.

Where I can found jars which nexus download? I mean what is the location of jars than were downloaded by nexus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default they go into the home directory of the user that tomcat is running as, in sonatype-work/nexus/storage  If tomcat is running as the tomcat user on a linux system, this would be /home/tomcat/sonatype-work/nexus/storage